# Word 2010: prevent zooming out switching to 2 page view

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, zoom

In Word 2010 when I zoom out at some point (depending on monitor-size and pixel settings) the view switches to 2 pages. I've tried several approaches but none works. When you zoom out further it will fit in more pages if it can.
What I want is to have one page, no matter how far I zoom out. From some googled answer I gather that this isn't possible. is there a way to keep Word displaying one page, no matter how far you zoom out?

Answer (score 0):

You can go around it, but zoom out the page, and in the same time scale the window to small size.
You can write macro for zoom out and scale down and assign hotkey for that.

[image]

You can see one page of word on a large screen.